# How to $set sub-sub-array items in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm developing a webapp which has a portal-ish component to it (think like multiple panels that can be drug around from column to column and added or removed).  I'm using MongoDB to store this info with a format like so...

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    title: 'My Layout',
    columns: [
        {
            order: 1,
            width: 30,
            panels: [
                { title: 'Panel Title', top: 100, content: '...' },
                { title: 'Panel Title', top: 250, content: '...' },
            ]
        },
        {
            ... multiple columns ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm attempting to use atomic/modifier operations with **update()** and this is getting confusing.  If I wanted to just update one property of a specific panel, how do I reference that?

```
update(
    { _id: ObjectId(...) },
    { $set: { columns.[???].panels.[???].top: 500 }
)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you know the index in the array you can access the array element directly using dot notation.

```
update(
{ _id: ObjectId(xxxx) },
{ $set: { 'columns.0.panels.0.top' : 125}}
)
```

Make sure you encase the dot notated path in quotes as a string.

**Edit:**

To give more detail on how this could work dynamically, I'll give an example in PHP:

```
$action = array("columns.$colNum.panels.$panelNum" => $newValue);
```

Yes there is the [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator), but it [does not appear to be advanced enough](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/8eef751f7c145dd7/925ecd9915760a58#641133a0588885cd) to change arrays within arrays, this may change in MongoDB 1.7.0

There is an alternative you can do instead of trying to stuff this information into a nested document. Try to flatten it out. You can create a collection that has panel & column objects:

column object:

```
{
_id: // MongoId
type: 'column',
user: 'username',
order: 1,
width: 30,
}
```

panel object:

```
{
_id: //MongoId
type: 'panel',
user: 'username',
parentColumn: //the columns _id string
top: 125,
left: 100
}
```

Then you can find all columns that belong to a user by doing:

```
find({ type: 'column', user:'username'});
```

You can find all panels for a specific column by doing:

```
find({type: 'panel', columnOwner:'ownerID'});
```

Since each column and panel will have a unique ID given by MongoDB to it, you can easily query and atomically set options.

```
update({'_id': ObjectId('idstring')}, {$set : { 'top' : 125}});
```

Comment: I'm wondering this too. Hard-coding the indexes really isn't that feasible. Still trying to figure out how to use the positional operator http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator

Answer (score 0):

I too had a situation like this, i followed $addToSet after $pull to replace i.e update what i needed.

```
 update(
{ _id: ObjectId(...) },
{ $addToSet: { columns.$.panels : "new sub-Doc" }
)
```

And then remove the old value

```
update({_id:ObjectId(....)},{$pull : { columns.$.panels : {"top" : 100} }})
```

Comment: What is the $ for on the columns?

Comment: "$" Acts as a placeholder to update the first element that matches the query condition in an update. please refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_