# Meteor/Mongo - add/update element in sub array dynamically

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I have found quite few related posts on SO on how to update a field in a sub array, such as this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473075/how-to-set-sub-sub-array-items-in-mongodb)

What I want to achieve is basically the same thing, but updating a field in a subarray dynamically, instead of just calling the field name in the query.
Now I also found how to do that straight in the main object, but cant seem to do it in the sub array.

Code to insert dynamically in sub-object:

```
_.each(data.data, function(val, key) {
  var obj = {};
  obj['general.'+key] = val;
  insert = 0 || (Documents.update(
    { _id: data._id },
    { $set: obj}
  ));
});
```

Here is the tree of what I am trying to do:

```
Documents: {
 _id: '123123'
 ...
 smallRoom:
  [
    _id: '456456'
    name: 'name1'
    description: 'description1'
  ],
  [
  ...
  ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
// insert a new object in smallRoom, with only the _id so far 
var newID = new Mongo.ObjectID;
var createId = {_id: newID._str};
Documents.update({_id: data._id},{$push:{smallRooms: createId}})
```

And the part to insert the other fields:

```
_.each(data.data, function(val, key) {
  var obj = {};
  obj['simpleRoom.$'+key] = val;
  console.log(Documents.update(
    { 
      _id: data._id,    <<== the document id that I want to update
      smallRoom: { 
        $elemMatch:{
          _id : newID._str,   <<== the smallRoom id that I want to update
        }
      }
    },
    { 
      $set: obj
    }
  ));
});
```

Ok, having said that, I understand I can insert the whole object straight away, not having to push every single field.

But I guess this question is more like, how does it work if smallRoom had 50 fields, and I want to update 3 random fields ? (So I would NEED to use the _each loop as I wouldnt know in advance which field to update, and would not want to replace the whole object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand your question, but I think the answer to what you are asking is to use the `$` symbol.

Example:

```
Documents.update(
    { 
      _id: data._id, smallRoom._id: newID._str
    },
    { 
      $set: { smallroom.$.name: 'new name' }
    }
);
```

You are finding the document that matches the `_id`: `data._id`, then finding the object in the array `smallRoom` that has an `_id` equal to `newId._str`. Then you are using the `$` sign to tell Mongo to update that object's `name` key.

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry about this stupid question... The problem was my code wasnt working. After trying few more things, I realised I start by pushing `smallRomms` and then update `simpleRooms`, which is not helping really... Then I forgot the `.` after the `$` in the set query. Sorry about that, Ill accept your answer but will probably delete the post as it is not relevant anymore